# How can I specify a return type for operator[]?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to explicitly specify a return type for overloaded `operator[]`?

For example, I have an object instance with an overloaded operator `[]`, and if I use `instance["num"]`, I'd like it to return an `int`, and `instance["flt"]` a `float` (there's already type handling logic), like this:

```
int some_value = instance["amount_of_entries"];
float other_value = instance["percentage"];
```

I've tried this:

```
class someClass {
    template<class T> T& operator[](char* index){ ... }
};

int val = instance["int_value"];
```

But I get an error:

```
error C2783: 'T &CSettings::operator [](char*)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

I thought of using `instance<int>["int_value"]`, but that's a syntax error and doesn't compile.

Comment: No. Why not using member functions : `int amountOfEntries()` and `float percentage()` ? That would be the c++ way of doing it.

Comment: @quantdev: because the `get`-prefixes are verbose and counter-productive in C++? getsin, as I use to say.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's your opinion (I renamed), anyway name the functions as you wish.

Comment: @AcidShout: you can use use separate member functions for each kind of logical result, e.g. `n_entries` (or `size`), and `percentage`.

Comment: @quantdev Because I'm trying to make a user-modify-able settings class. Aka I have a class which has a set amount of settings (e.g. `maxAmountOfX:int`, `modeOfSomething:char*`, etc) which are then used by my program's logic, but I also want them to be able to be modified by the user with a simple `instance[user_input[0]] = parse_user_input(user_input[1]);` instead of a huge if like `if(user_input[0] == "maxAmountOfX"){ this->maxAmountOfX = user_input[1]; } ...`

Comment: @AcidShout: you can make one accessor for each supported type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So there's no way of doing it with templates? I was trying to do it with templates to avoid exactly that -- repeating code for different types

Comment: You could try a generically named method, eg `setting` and call it as `int value = instance.setting<int>("int_value");`. Not quite the operator syntax you wanted but could work.

Comment: @Niall I see. Will use `instance.setting<>()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no way to do this easily with the operators. The syntax would look something like;

```
instance.operator[]<int>("int_value");
```

Alternatives could include returning something like `any`; as part of boost or the upcoming library extensions.

You could try a generically named method, e.g. `setting` and call it as;

```
int value = instance.setting<int>("int_value");
```

Not quite the operator syntax you wanted but could work. It is easier to specify a return on a templated function than with an operator.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no nice way of doing this with `operator[]` and operators keeping it *that* nice. The problem is mainly that if you are going the template way, for the return type, you'll have to explicitly call `operator[]<Type>(...)` and variations of this.

On the other hand you could return a generic [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any.html) that will then later casted to the proper type by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that may work for you:

```
#include <iostream>

class someClass {
    public:
    template<class T> T operator[](char* index){
        return T();
    }
};

int main()
{
    someClass foo;
    std::cout << foo.operator[]<int>("some int");
    std::cout << foo.operator[]<double>("some double");
    int bar = 42;
    std::cin >> bar;
    return 0;
}
```

I changed it from returning a reference to returning an instance. And the call to the function is not as nice, but that's the only way I know of to compile a function call to a templated operator[].